# Which API should I use to implement search on my website

Tags: java, search, full-text-search

We have an in-house webapp running for internal use over the intranet for our firm.

Recently we decided to implement an efficient searching facility,and would want inputs from experts here about what all API's are available and which one would be most useful for the following use-cases:

- The objects are divided into business groups in our firm, i.e an object can actually have various attributes, and the attributes as such are not common between any two objects from different BG(Business Groups)
- Users might want to search for a specific attribute amongst an object
- Users are from a business group, hence they have an idea about the kind of attributes related to their group
- The API should be generic enough to have a full text/part text search if a list of object is passed to it, with the name of the attribute and the search text.More importantly it should be able to index this result.

As this is an internal app, there are no restrictions on the space as such, but we need a fast and generic API.

I am sure Java already has something which suits our needs.

More info on the technology stack:
Language:Java
Server: Apache Tomcat
Stack : Spring, iBatis, Struts
Cache in place : ECache
Other API : Shindig API

### Thanks

Neeraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Solr for Apache Lucene if text based search has priotity. It might be more that what you want though have a look.

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

http://lucene.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

Solr is a great tool for search. The downside is that it may require some work to get it the way you want it.

With it, you can set different fields for a document and give them custom priority in each query.

You can create facets easily from those fields like with Amazon. Sorting is easy and quick. And has a spellchecker and suggestions engine built in.

The documents are matched using the query mode [dismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMax) which you can [customize](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin).